# Higher precision logarithms

Tags: arduino-ide, library

I need to produce a log to base 10 with at least 4 decimal places. However, the log10 inbuilt function is giving the output with only two decimal places. What do I do? Is there a different function or a library that I can use?

Comment: How are you displaying the values? The number of decimal places you are seeing is probably a byproduct of the way you are converting them to strings, not of the underlying math. Most Arudino math is done with the `float` type, which should have about 6 or 7 decimal digits of precision.

Comment: I was just using a Serial.print without specifying any precision. This works, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get 6 or 7 decimal places out of the Arudino float type. Try using Serial.print for floats with a number of decimal places. Something like this:

```
float x = log10(3.141592658);
Serial.print(x, 6);
```